# XBee TX line Drop

Tags: uart, xbee

I am using an Xbee 900HP in API mode using UART. I am transmitting a command to it using my micro and expecting a response. Based on my Oscilloscope waveforms the data i expect back is being received however it it followed shortly after by a slow curved drop in the UART line. Has anyone else experience this?

I have attached pictures of the packet received as well as the "curved drop" that follows for your reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the data sheet say regards this "anomaly"?

Comment: Nothing that I have been able to find (have read it back to front multiple times). I have found that placing a 10K pull up resistor on the RX line of my Micro has eliminated the "drop" but hasn't exactly answered my questions.